# Datastax OpsCenter LDAP Configuration Error

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have configured LDAP settings for datastax OpsCenter authentication. Though the app is able to find the account in the search (got this details by enabling debug option for additional logging), but at the end getting an exception as below,

```
2017-05-05 22:30:18,658 [opscenterd] DEBUG: Unbind successful (PoolThread-twisted.internet.reactor-2)
2017-05-05 22:30:18,658 [ClusterTest] DEBUG: received a NoD, closing everything (NioProcessor-1)
2017-05-05 22:30:18,662 [opscenterd]  WARN: Unauthorized while calling LoginController: User filter insufficient to uniquely identify users. (MainThread)
```

Could someone guide me if i'm missing anything here ?

Below are the LDAP settings i have configured in my configuration file (opcenterd.conf),

```
server_host = myad01.test.domain.com    
server_port = 389    
uri_scheme = ldaps     
search_dn = CN=ldap-account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com     
search_password = *******    
user_search_base = dc=test,dc=domain,dc=com     
user_search_filter = (sAMAccountName={0})     
admin_group_name = DB Admin, DB Dev    
user_memberof_attribute = memberof
```